# Purchasing assets from the Unity Assets store without organization information

Tags: unity-game-engine, payment

how to buy an asset in the unity asset store if I don't have a real organization? ask any follow up questions as I don't know anything about this issue.
[image]
I don't want to do this operation through third party resources. this asset will be used in google play game

I tried changing subscriptions but it doesn't work. I also searched for information about this on the Internet, but did not find anything.

Comment: Just fill it in. Click you have to pay tax. Im not a company either

Comment: Just use a temporary name, if you do publish a game update it before you do.

Comment: @BugFinder Should I use my house address or am I misunderstanding? I don't have a registered company

Comment: yes, use your details, theres quite a lot of individuals not companies who buy frmo teh asset store

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you! And one more question: does this information go to the tax authorities of the country? And do I have to use the address from my place of residence, since I now live in another country?

Comment: you should use your place of residence.. I believe it mainly uses it to work out how to charge you the right tax for your country and im sure they pay taxes (unlike say Amazon)